# Why does a sine wave speed up and slow down?

Tags: trigonometry, wave-equation

I was playing with the resource linked below, which allows you to see how the value of sine changes as the angle changes. I understand that the hypotenuse side must move faster than the adjacent side shrinks in order for both to reach the y axis at the same time, but I'm pretty much lost from there. Can someone explain slowly and simply why the sine does not change at a consistent speed?

https://www.mathopenref.com/triggraphsine.html

Comment: Well, if it changed at a constant speed, it would eventually exceed any finite number; in particular, it would exceed the hypotenuse, which it clearly cannot do. ¶ More directly, if you're going in a circle around a compass rose (from east to north to west to south back to east again), then sine would be how far north or south you are, and cosine is how far east or west you are.  Sine changes fastest when you are at east or west, and slowest (in fact, momentarily stationary) when you are at north or south.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the cosine is slowing down when the sine is speeding up and vice versa.

Comment: Broadly speaking, yes.  The constant hypotenuse acts as a kind of "yoke" that places a cap on the total amount of change that the two functions can collectively undergo.

Comment: Sine is not a linear function - it varies according to the position around  the circumference of a circle which also influences the tangent and the cosine; please see this link half way down the page for a similar sort of setup which you have: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trigonometry.html